# Agrupar Array de objetos por valor y concatenar demás valores en uno

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

Amigos, Tengo una duda, Como puedo hacer para mapear y reducir un array como este

```js
let array = [
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "91,29", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "8,71", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" }
];
array.map(r=>r.VALOR=parseFloat(r.VALOR));
console.log(array);
```

y quisiera poder hacer esto con el array

```
[
    {
        ITEM: "Avicennia germinans",
        VALOR: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 91.26, 0]
    },
    {
        ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa",
        VALOR: [...]
    },
    {
        ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle",
        VALOR: [...]
    },
    {
        ITEM: "Sp. manglar",
        VALOR: [...]
    }
]
```

Alguna sugerencia para llegar a lo que necesito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `reduce` para ir creando el array resultado.

En este ejemplo la función que utiliza para "reducir" el array:

Comprueba si el `ITEM` está incluido y si no lo añade al resultado
Comprueba que `VALOR` sea un valor numérico válido y, si es así, lo añade al array `VALOR` del elemento (reemplazando el separador decimal para realizar la conversión correctamente)

```js
let array = [
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "91,29", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "8,71", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" }
];
// Utilizo el método reduce para ir creando el array resultante
let result = array.reduce((prev, current, index, arr) => {
  // Compruebo si ya existe el elemento
  let exists = prev.find(x => x.ITEM === current.ITEM);
  // Si no existe lo creo con un array vacío en VALOR
  if (!exists) {
    exists = {ITEM: current.ITEM, VALOR: []};
    prev.push(exists);
  }
  // Si el elemento actual tiene VALOR lo añado al array del
  // elemento existente
  if (current.VALOR != null){
    // Convierto el valor a numérico reemplazando el carácter separador
    let val = parseFloat(current.VALOR.replace(',','.'));
    // Si es un valor numérico válido lo añado al resultado
    if (!isNaN(val)){
      exists.VALOR.push(val);
    }
  }
  // Devuelvo el array resultado para la nueva iteración
  return prev;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Con un cambio mínimo podrías comprobar también si el valor numérico está repetido y, en tal caso, no incluirlo. No sé si es algo que te interese en tu caso:

```js
let array = [
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "91,29", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "8,71", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" }
];
// Utilizo el método reduce para ir creando el array resultante
let result = array.reduce((prev, current, index, arr) => {
  // Compruebo si ya existe el elemento
  let exists = prev.find(x => x.ITEM === current.ITEM);
  // Si no existe lo creo con un array vacío en VALOR
  if (!exists) {
    exists = {ITEM: current.ITEM, VALOR: []};
    prev.push(exists);
  }
  // Si el elemento actual tiene VALOR lo añado al array del
  // elemento existente
  if (current.VALOR != null){
    // Convierto el valor a numérico reemplazando el carácter separador
    let val = parseFloat(current.VALOR.replace(',','.'));
    // Si es un valor numérico válido lo añado al resultado
    if (!isNaN(val) && exists.VALOR.indexOf(val) < 0){
      exists.VALOR.push(val);
    }
  }
  // Devuelvo el array resultado para la nueva iteración
  return prev;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Basado en tu respuesta construí esto
_[https://codepen.io/m4xd34th/pen/bYzNML](https://codepen.io/m4xd34th/pen/bYzNML)_
Elimine la validación de si es un valor numérico válido debido a que los datos provienen de una APIRest y ya vienen avalados desde la base de datos, pero no venían organizados de manera adecuada para las necesidades del frontend

Answer (score 1):

Hola una forma de resolver lo que propones, es la siguiente:

```js
let array = [
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "91,29", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "8,71", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { ITEM: "Sp. manglar" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Avicennia germinans" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Laguncularia racemosa" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Rhizophora mangle" },
    { VALOR: "0", ITEM: "Sp. manglar" }
];
let result = [];

/**
 * elementExist
 * Comprueba si el valor de la clave ITEM ya se encuentra 
 * como valor de algun objeto del array.
 * Devuelve el indice del elemento en caso de existir, 
 * de lo contrario false.
 */
const elementExist = (array, value) => {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < array.length) {
    if (array[i].ITEM == value) return i;
    i++;
  }
  return false;
}

array.forEach((e) => {
  let i = elementExist(result, e.ITEM);
  if (i === false) {
    // Si no existe, creo agrego un nuevo objeto.
    result.push({
      "ITEM": e.ITEM,
      "VALOR": [e.VALOR]
    });
  } else {
    // Si el ya existe agrego el nuevo elemento a el array valor.
    result[i].VALOR.push(e.VALOR);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Lo que realiza el script en pocas palabras es: recorre uno a uno los elementos del array, en primer lugar utiliza la función auxiliar `elementExist` (ver comentario de la función), en caso de que no exista un objeto con el mismo valor para la clave `ITEM`, agrega un nuevo objeto a el array `result` (fijate que la clave VALUE ahora es un array). En caso contrario simplemente agrego el valor de la clave `VALOR` al el objeto determinado por la variable i.